# iMac Calls Panic Debugger on Startup

Tags: macos, boot, mac

My iMac (27-inch, Late 2012, running macOS Sierra) calls the panic debugger (see included pictures) every time I first start it up in the morning. If I then force a reboot by holding down the power button until the screen goes dark and then pressing it again, the iMac starts up as it should and everything works just fine.

Should I be worried? Is there anything I can do about this?

[image: Picture 1]

[image: Picture 2]